# How can i change the date type to the format YYYY-DD-MM

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In a form i have given type ="date", By default iam getting date format as dd-mm-yyyy. How can i change the format to yyyy-mm-dd. below is the sample code, Please help me on this

Comment: _"How can I change the format"_: Where (JavaScript or in the form, PHP) and why?

Comment: need in javascript? or in php?

Comment: are you looking for a javascript code?

Comment: Are you posting the data to php?

Comment: in just need to make changes in the date format, any coding will be okay

Comment: Javascript solution [http://jsfiddle.net/ttm5g6yq/](http://jsfiddle.net/ttm5g6yq/)

Answer (score -3):

Use PHP `strtotime()` function to convert. Let Suppose you will get

```
<?php

$date1 = "20-12-2018";

//now convert it using the strtotime function

$date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date1));
```

Read Full Documentation [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)